# Java JPEG Palette Swap

Tags: java, jpeg

I'm trying to invert a JPEG image in Java, and I want to know if there's a way to modify the color palette instead of changing the image one pixel at a time. I want an efficient solution and the most efficient solution I can think of is inverting the color palette itself.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: JPEGs don't have color palettes. Going over each pixel is probably your best bet though.

Comment: Thank you.. I didn't know. This is the first time I've dabbled in image processing

Comment: In some systems, you can convert the JPEG to use a palette. If you need fast color changes, while sacrificing image quality, you can go that way.